# Japanese spelling and meaning of "conohen" or "conoheng"?

Tags: words

I heard the word "conohen" in a video (pronounced somewhat like "conoheng").

What is the word and what does it mean?

Is it kansaiben?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is regular standard Japanese この辺 which means “in these parts, around here”.

Comment: @Gimme Note that in roman text it is normally written 'kono hen'.

Comment: hmm yes it seems that was why i couldn't find it